# Please explain '$a' bash variable used in sed command for converting text to HTML

Tags: bash, sed

I have been following some bash tutorials online. I was learning about sed in this tutorial [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_05_03.html). Essentially, some text is injected into a HTML 'pre' element.

The input text is as follows (named 'test'):

```
line1
line2
line3
```

The following HTML template is saved as a shell file and is referenced in the main shell script. The template looks like this (named `script.sed`):

```
1i\
<html>\
<head><title>sed generated html</title></head>\
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">\
<pre>
$a\ <!-- what is this variable? -->
</pre>\
</body>\
</html>
```

The following script is run from the shell and references the 'test' file as input (named `txt2html.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

# This is a simple script that you can use for converting text into HTML.
# First we take out all newline characters, so that the appending only happens
# once, then we replace the newlines.

echo "converting $1..."

SCRIPT="/home/sandy/scripts/script.sed"
NAME="$1"
TEMPFILE="/var/tmp/sed.$PID.tmp"
sed "s/\n/^M/" $1 | sed -f $SCRIPT | sed "s/^M/\n/" > $TEMPFILE
mv $TEMPFILE $NAME

echo "done."
```

The script is run like so:

```
txt2html.sh test
```

The output is:

```
<html>
<head><title>sed generated html</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<pre>
line1
line2
line3
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the `$a` variable in the `script.sed` file? I have never come across `$a` before. How does it work in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$a` in the sed script is not a variable. `$` means the end of the file, and `a` is the append command. So the `$a` means, on the last line of the file, append some text.

Comment: So this essentially means - "Replace the line feeds with carriage returns (^M) in file 'test' and append this resulting text at the end of the line between the 'pre' tags in 'script.sed' and then replace the carriage returns (^M) with new lines?"

Comment: To be a bit more precise: "replace the line feeds with carriage returns (^M), prepend an html header, append an html footer, and then replace the carriage returns (^M) with new lines"

Comment: Thanks for the help